# Highlighting keywords in Ubuntu search

Tags: 19.10, directory, search

I would like to see the keywords which I write in the search field of a folder highlighted in the results.

Could you tell me if it is possible to set this option please?

Comment: Hi @ParsaMousavi my question is about ubuntu 19.10. I'm doing an example: If I write the word "myfile" in the search toolbar in a **folder**, i'd like to see all the istances of the word myfile highlighted.

Comment: There's no settings about that in the out-of-the-box nautilus and also there's no extension which can do that in the repository.I don't know if there exist such an extension at all,but if you have no problem with command-line, you can use ```find . | grep something```.It has the feature you want but it's not in nautilus

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion @ParsaMousavi

Comment: @ParsaMousavi how can i specify that i want to search capitol letter and lowercase letter, for example Google and google?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi You can use the option `-i` to make the search case-insensitive.Without that , **Google** and **google** is different.

Comment: sorry for the nuisance @ParsaMousavi I have some problem to search more than one word..how can i search two words (e.g. google forms)?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Put them in double quotes, like this ```grep -i "google forms"```.And if you want to use special characters like ```-``` you have to escape it : ```grep "google\-forms"```

Comment: @ParsaMousavi it works only if the word forms follows google...in general, if I've the folder called (this is my folder), and if i search "this folder", the bash doesn't give me any result

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi For that you can use ```grep "this.*folder"```.As you can see it's more flexible than a search utility in a file manager.For more information  see [this](https://www.ostechnix.com/the-grep-command-tutorial-with-examples-for-beginners/) or you can use the manpage : ```man grep```

Answer (score 0):

If you would exactly specify your case of finding words i.e in what way you need to find the desired word(s), then we can make a regular expression ( basically a language of pattern which the computer understands ), then the `grep` utility find that expression for you as correctly pointed out to you in the comments above by [Parsa Mousavi](https://askubuntu.com/users/1001338/parsa-mousavi).

Comment: Hello @AaryanBHAGAT i'm looking for an option to highlight the words which I search in a folder, not in the terminal.

Comment: `search in a folder, not in the terminal`  by this you mean the search bar which appears on the top of ubuntu? You can very well search the entire folder using the terminal.